# Why terminal responds very slow?

Tags: command-line, gnome

I have faced this annoying behavior of terminal in gnome under Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS. Even the first time I open the terminal, it starts blinking and after 1-2 min, gives the message

```
groups: cannot find name for group ID 1096358339
```

After that, it operates normally. But every tab in terminal or new terminal, the same story. Any idea why?

And when I try to find the group by

```
cat /etc/group | grep "1096358339"
```

I do not get any output (also running `sudo` takes ages).

Comment: You shoud use: `cat /etc/group | grep "1096358339"`

Comment: typo, I had done that!

Comment: Useless use of `cat` spotted!!! Please consider `grep "1096358339" /etc/group` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your user has been added to an invalid group. Run `grep {your username} /etc/passwd` and your user-group number is the 4th field (usually a number just before your full name). In Ubuntu you should be in a group of the same name (and number) as your user. For you this is probably set to 1096358339 for some reason, so set it to be the same as the number in the 3rd column, which is your user number.

Also, if this is the case, you may need to fix your files after you change your group or they have invalid ownership. Run `chown -R {your username}:{your username}` from your home directory, substituting in your yoursername.